# How to check size of folders that OneDrive is backing up?

Tags: onedrive

I have 300 GB in a subdirectory on my computer that I am backing up under OneDrive. I would like to check the folder size in OneDrive so I know it is all getting backed up. **How do I display the folder size**?

I have tried to do this through the OneDrive website with no success, as follows: I go to the [Office website](https://www.office.com), click the OneDrive icon, and get a webpage like https://myCompany-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myName_myCompany_com/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx . It lists my folders with the following info: Name, Modified, Modified By, File Size, Sharing, Activity. However nothing is shown in File Size. When I click on the Gear icon in the webpage upper right and search for 'Size', no settings are found. When I right click on the folder and choose 'Details' from the popup, Activity events are listed (worryingly, most are 'You deleted file myFile.bin 4 days ago'), but the folder size is not listed. I tried the tip at the end [here](https://forums.windowscentral.com/onedrive/452198-how-do-i-determine-size-folder-my-onedrive.html) but get no results under the Gear icon when I search for 'Storage Metrics' or Documents. FYI I am a lowly user, not the administrator of OneDrive at my company.

Comment: Does the method [specified here](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/5ec6da77-2cab-4d06-8f36-22b63d6d1767) work for you?

Comment: @harrymc Interestingly, the only Folder properties I get under Info are Type, Modified, Path. You show one additional one, File Size, which I don't have. Do you happen to know if this is an option that a OneDrive administrator could set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't figured out how to do this from the OneDrive website, but [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-your-OneDrive-for-Business-storage-31519161-059C-4764-B6F8-F5CD29F7FE68) is another way, under 'Manage your storage in the new OneDrive for Business sync client'. If you follow the steps, you get a webpage displaying the size of each folder and subfolder. (Why this information isn't available from the OneDrive webpage folder listing is beyond me).